# Does there exist an infinite subset $X$ from the set of positive integers such that the sum of any two elements of $X$ is square-free?

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist an infinite subset $X$ from the set of positive integers such that the sum of any two elements of $X$ is square-free?

Can anyone give me some hints? I really don't know what to start with. Thanks!